# Passing Array Variables using POST or GET with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help trying to serialize a hidden element in html than pass the value into php with post. Here is my code:

```
<form action = "index.php" method = "POST" >
Enter name: <input type ="text" name = "name"><br></br>
enter ID: <input type = "text" name = "id"><br></br>
<input type = "hidden"
id = "hiddenStrArr"
name "hiddenStrArr"
value = "<?php print base64_encode(serialize("$arrayVar"))?>">
<input type = "submit" name = "submitButton" value = "Submit">
</form>

<?php
$nameExists = FALSE;
$name = ($_POST['name']);
$id = ($_POST['id']);
$hiddenStrArr = $_POST["hiddenStrArr"];
$arrayVar = unserialize(base64_decode($hiddenArray));
```

I have an array in my php in a foreach loop that will check the input from a user with data in my array. The problem is that my array stays the same. If I post again it will start with the old array all over again, but I would like for it to be update with the user input. I'm trying to follow this guide [Passing Array Variables using POST or GET with PHP](http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=11) and I don't understand it well. Would someone please help me or explain how this works. I am getting an error saying that $name $id $hiddenStrArr and $arrayVar are index undefined. Thank you.

Here's more of the code to help explain what's going on:

```
 <?php
    $myTwoDimArr = array(1 =>  array("name1", 0, "123"),
    2 => array("name2", 123, "456"),
    3 =>  array("name3", 456, "789"),
    4 =>  array("name3", 789, "101112"));
    ?>

    <form action = "index.php" method = "POST" >
    Enter name: <input type ="text" name = "name"><br></br>
    enter ID: <input type = "text" name = "id"><br></br>

<input type = "hidden"
id = "hiddenStrArr"
name "hiddenStrArr"
value = "<?php print base64_encode(serialize("$arrayVar"))?>">
<input type = "submit" name = "submitButton" value = "Submit">
</form>

    <?php
    $nameExists = FALSE;
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $id = ($_POST['id']);
    $hiddenStrArr = $_POST["hiddenStrArr"];
    $arrayVar = unserialize(base64_decode($hiddenArray));
    //this will check values from the html form against
    //the values stored in the array than add 5 to $value[1]
    foreach($myTwoDimArr as $key => $value){
        if($key == $id && $value[0] == $name){
        $myTwoDimArr[$key][1] = $myTwoDimArr[$key][1] + 5;
        $nameExists = TRUE;
        }
    }               //if values don't exist this creates a new element
                    //in the declared array
                    if ($nameExists === FALSE){
                        $newData = array($name, 1, date("Y-m-d"));
                        $myTwoDimArr[$id] = $newData;
                    }
    //this will print values from the array
    //the values are not being saved, I was hoping to use
    //hidden element to accomplish this so that user may input
    //more new values or add to existing values
    foreach($myTwoDimArr as $key => $value){
                        echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>
                                    <td>".htmlspecialchars($value[0])."</td>
                                    <td>".htmlspecialchars($value[1])."</td>
                                    <td>".htmlspecialchars($value[2])."</td></tr>";
                    }

    ?>
```

Comment: If you have any other way of passing this data around, do that. Sticking it in the form is asking for someone to tamper with it.

Comment: in the last line of your code you are unserializing $hiddenArray, it does not appear elsewhere in your code sample - shouldn't it be $hiddenStrArr?

Comment: @tadman that's ok it's for a home project I'm trying to do for experience/educational. No one will tamper with it unless my wife learns how :P

Comment: If you're learning, that's fine, but it also means you should be learning to do it in a way that isn't so quirky and covolulted that it can be applied to real-world situations.

Comment: @lovelace not sure what you mean, please elaborate further

Comment: See answer @jordikroon - he has changed `$arrayVar = unserialize(base64_decode($hiddenArray));` into `$arrayVar = unserialize(base64_decode($hiddenStrArray));`

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are defined below you render the form. That's why you're getting undefined errors. The variables don't exist at that moment.

What you should do in this case, and what I'd recommend in almost any case is to output your html at the very last. Thus computing before rendering.

```
<?php
    $nameExists = FALSE;
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    $hiddenStrArr = isset($_POST['hiddenStrArr']) ? $_POST['hiddenStrArr'] : '';
    $arrayVar = unserialize(base64_decode($hiddenStrArr));
?>

<form action = "index.php" method = "POST" >
    Enter name: <input type ="text" name = "name"><br></br>
    enter ID: <input type = "text" name = "id"><br></br>
    <input type = "hidden"
    id = "hiddenStrArr"
    name "hiddenStrArr"
    value = "<?php print base64_encode(serialize("$arrayVar"))?>">
    <input type = "submit" name = "submitButton" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: still getting the same undefined index. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Probably because you don't check if the POST values are set before using them. You can use "isset" for that. I've edited the code. Also note that in this example, the $name and $id aren't used. You'll likely want to print them as value in the input fields.

Comment: maybe cleaner, if you just check for 'submit' being set, as follows: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $nameExists = FALSE;
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $hiddenStrArr = $_POST["hiddenStrArr"];
    $arrayVar = unserialize(base64_decode($hiddenStrArr));
 }`

Comment: It's cleaner to use a submit variable, or even better is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'. In both cases you'd still want to check if the POST variables exists otherwise you'll get undefined index warnings when someone unfriendly person is manipulating the page.

Comment: it's working, but the array is still not storing the values from previous input. for example if i have array[0] = apples and user inputs oranges than inputs banana I would want there to be array[1] = oranges and array[2] = banana to be created and stored as output. I have a for loop setup to make these changes, but they are not being stored and saved. As of now i'm still suck with the default list in my array.

Comment: @JordiKroon Let me share more of the code maybe it will help explain will post is as an answer, it's too long for comments

Comment: @JordiKroon ok, I just updated the original post. I'm confused how to store the input data in the form using hidden element. The point is for the data to be saved and the array to reflect the changes instead of only applying the changes once than reverting to original array values.